# is_executable(): open_basedir restriction in effect in plesk server

Tags: plesk

I had a problem with plesk server . when i run the my website it showsis_executable(): open_basedir restriction in effect.

```
File(/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/rescuefirst.com/:/tmp/:/mnt/
Please Help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the PHP option `open_basedir to none` at Domains > webmail.example.com > PHP Settings. Refer [plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214029509-Unable-to-attach-files-in-a-custom-Roundcube-installation-realpath-open-basedir-restriction-in-effect)

Comment: Thanks its fix the issue. You have a done great job.